# Selection of dynamic rows from tableview (iOS app-KIF framework)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, kif

I am facing issue for capturing of dynamically generated rows.
I want to select row from table view which gets generated dynamically.
When i try to access that cell with following code it gives me error like 
**“Cell not found”**

```
[app.tables[@”Presets List”].cells[@”Express”] tap];
```

OR

```
[app.tables[@”Presets List”].cells.staticTexts[@”Express”] tap];
```

Could you please help in the same?

Comment: R u code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath please provide some code when and where the app was crashed?

Comment: I am trying to capture code through record and play. But click action on dynamically generated rows not generating any code.

    XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];

    XCUIElement *taskNameTextField = app.textFields[@"Task name"];

    [taskNameTextField tap];

    [taskNameTextField typeText:@"add task name"];

    [app.navigationBars[@"Timer"].buttons[@"Presets"] tap];
// app crashed here because code did not get generated for selected row 
    [app.buttons[@"Start Working"] tap];
    [app.buttons[@"Give Up"] tap];

Comment: can you post the code you have done in your project in your question because you post question more descriptive the more answer you get. Don't go with the question size because if you post more understandable question the more you get answers.

Comment: I am trying to automate solanum app.
[link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/61419/ios-ui-testing-with-kif)
Steps I am following are :
1. Add task name
2. Click on presets button
3. Select "Express" (here app crashes)
4. Select start working

Comment: i will check this demo when i will free. Thank u!